# docker-machine, create and run a nginx container is not exposing port 80

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-machine

From this [article](http://networkstatic.net/docker-on-google-compute-engine-using-docker-machine/) it was really easy to "docker-machine create" a VM host on google compute engine. My problem is that when using the ip(docker-machine NameOfVM) to access a running nginx container it does not responde.

I can see that nginx is running, when I SSH into the VM and run "curl localhost".
I can ping the VM but curl or browser is not responding.

Do you know what I am missing?

ifconfig shows a docker0 adapter and a eth0. 
Do I have to configure docker any further? As I understand, docker is not running any boot2docker/VM's on a linux machine?

Thanks

Comment: Is it just not responding or do you get any kind of error?

Comment: I can ping the machine alright, but curl or browser http is just not responding?

Comment: I've got _zero_ idea, but I hear this is pretty good: irc://irc.freenode.net/#google-containers

Comment: I suspect there is a firewall rule in the way - go into the network settings and have a look

Comment: I suspect there is a firewall rule in the way - go into the network settings and have a look

Comment: Yes, I can see that the google driver created a "docker-machines 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:2376 docker-machine"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read [firewall section of the Google Compute Engine docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#networks_1) to configure your firewall:

> You can also create a firewall rule that allows HTTP traffic from anywhere to all instances on the example-network network. Execute the following:
>
> ```
> $ gcloud compute firewall-rules create web --network example-network --allow tcp:80`
> ```